# PHP SOAP for https URL

Tags: php, soap

I am consuming a WCF service where everything works fine with Test URL `http://domain.com/service.svc?wsdl`. I get the following error in the production system with URL `https://domain.com/service.svc?wsdl`

Error Received in the Response:

```
The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

The IP address of the client server is white listed and I am authorized to send API request. I confirmed this with the Vendor too. I was also said it might be a problem with `HTTPS`

Here is the SOAP request:

```
$data = array('UserName'=>$username,'Password'=>$password,'IPAddress'=>$ip,'searchCriteria'=>$search);

$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_2,
            "trace"=>1,
            "exceptions"=>0
            );

$client = new SoapClient('https://api.malindoair.com/GQWCF_FlightEngine/FlightBookingService.svc?wsdl',$params);

$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','Action','http://tempuri.org/IFlightBookingService/SearchFlight');

$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);

$retval = $client->SearchFlight($data);
```

I do not want to try nusoap because the test environment is working fine.